# Azure Data Factory V2 Pipeline activity Stuck in "In Progress"

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory V2 Pipeline submit USQL activity. USQL Job showing succeded but ADFV2 pipeline Stuck in "In Progress".

[ADFV2 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6HrE.png)
[ADLA status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWUlY.png)

Comment: Can you share more information? Such as some screenshots and what you have attempted already to resolve the issue?

Comment: First job succeeded and triggered 2nd activity.
 
2nd activity submitted USQL job and USQL Job succeeded in ADLA but ADFV2 still showing in progress and not proceeding further.
 
As its not proceeding further job is on hold.